# Bootstrap table-responsive; table won't fill whole wrapper

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

To the best of my knowledge, the way to use bootstrap's table-responsive is by wrapping it on a div with table-responsive class:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="table">
 </table>
</div>
```

However, when trying to apply some CSS to it I'm unsure if I should do it on `<table>` or `<div class=table-responsive>`. When doing it on `<table>` they don´t seem to act accordingly (I still see the table layout from the `div`; e.g. coloring `table` background the borders will not be aligned with it).
So I was applying the CSS on the `div` .Seems to be working nicely, except for the fact I will always get an extra unwanted layer on my table [(IMG_ `table ends at *Não Urgentes* row` )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tshwj.png).

So where should I style the table and how would I do in a way in which I won't be styling the `div`?

**Demo**
https://jsfiddle.net/e8Lz10td/

Answer (score 0):

There is a margin-bottom on the .table class and you only need to declare `<tbody>` once and place all body content into it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `table-responsive` at div and add another to `<table>`. [image]

Comment: But that way the styles are not being applied(e.g. the border-radius); that's why I putted the classes on ```div``; and why I was wondering the correct tag to put them on

Comment: Sorry i dont know how to fix that